# Flask - Why does writing to file before shutdown, often write only an empty file?

Tags: python, file, flask, uwsgi, atexit

I tried to prototype a website with flask and instead of using a database,
I wanted to save the websites state to two json files on shutdown of the server.

While this works on my computer, on my server one of the files often is not
correctly written and all I get is an empty file.

I think this has to do with me using uwsgi to serve the website instead
of flasks debug server, I did however set the number of threads uwsgi uses to 1 by setting *processes = 1* in a configuration file.

```
from flask import Flask
import json
import atexit
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


def save():
    with open('file.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       json.dump(something_large, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    with open('other_file.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       json.dump(something_small, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

atexit.register(save)
```